# Syntax error calculating the average of student marks while reading from a text file

Tags: python, average

```
f = open('studMarks.txt', 'r')
marks = 0
# Sort out names, split the words then sort which order
    for line in f:
    words = line.split()
    fname = words[0]
    lname = words[1]
    print(f"{lname},{fname}")
f.close()

f = open('studMarks.txt', 'r')
sum = 0
count = 0
for line in f:
    count += 1
    sum += float(line.split()[2])
    n = []
average = sum/count

print(f"{average}")
```

When using the `for` loop it seems to display a value of 64.3, which I believe is for the total of the whole student list and average for all marks.

I need to produce the an output which displays the student names and average on the same line. I can do for the names but I cannot do it for the average as I keep getting errors. I don't know what to input in.

Comment: Please share the input file data.

Comment: Indent your code properly.

Comment: It is properly indented in my file just the website it is different, I don't know how to calculate the average for each line for example Student Name // Marks 30, 50, 60 ,100, 70

Comment: Without saying what errors you get, it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the full solution. The `with open` line is a context manager and ensures that the file will get closed as soon as you exit the block. You should get used to using this style as it's the safe way to do I/O. The rest is just bog standard Python.

```
marks=dict()
with open('studMarks.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        fname = words[0]
        lname = words[1]
        score = int(words[2])
        key = f'{fname} {lname}'
        count_key = f'{fname} {lname}_count'
        latest_score = score + (marks.get(key)[0] if marks.get(key) else 0)
        latest_count = 1 + (marks.get(key)[1] if marks.get(key) else 0)
        marks[key] = (latest_score, latest_count )
for name, value in marks.items():
    print(f'{name} : {value[0]/value[1]}')
```

Comment: Curious to know if this solution worked for you Johnny?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply Adam, I've spent today working. BUT THANK YOU SO MUCH IT WORKED!!!!

Comment: Great. The important part of this is that you need to make sure that each time you come across a name that you've seen before, you add the current score to the previous score (which is what latest_score above does) and keep a running total. Then you just keep a count of how many times you've seen each name (see latest_count) and store this in the right data structure (which in my case is a dictionary). Then the rest is easy (divide one by the other and print it out!). Glad you're all up and running now!

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem.
From what I understand you have a text file that looks like this:
`Johnny Ly 90 100 Adam Best 80 30 Tim Smith 10 20` in a file called `studentMarks2.txt`
and want output like this:
`Johnny_Ly 95.0 Adam_Best 55.0 Tim_Smith 15.0`
if that is true then it can be done using code like this without pandas or csv
though those would make this a lot easier.

```
fileContents = []

with open('studMarks2.txt','r') as f:
    fileContents = f.read().split()
    

students = dict()

names = []
for content in fileContents:
    if content.isnumeric():
        studentKey = '_'.join(names)
        currentScore = students.get(studentKey,[])        
        newScore = currentScore + [float(content)]
        students.update({studentKey:newScore})        
    else:
        if len(names) == 2:
            names.clear()
            names.append(content)
        else:
            names.append(content)
            
for student,scores in students.items():
    avg = sum(scores)/len(scores)
    print(student,avg,end=' ')
```

Broken down
This part reads the contents and splits on white space

```
fileContents = []    
    with open('studMarks2.txt','r') as f:
        fileContents = f.read().split()
```

this part then iterates through the contents
storing the names as keys in a dictionary and putting the scores in a list

```
students = dict()        
    names = []
    for content in fileContents:
        if content.isnumeric():
            studentKey = '_'.join(names)
            currentScore = students.get(studentKey,[])        
            newScore = currentScore + [float(content)]
            students.update({studentKey:newScore})        
        else:
            if len(names) == 2:
                names.clear()
                names.append(content)
            else:
                names.append(content)
```

Lastly it iterates over the dictionary and output the avg on one line

```
for student,scores in students.items():
    avg = sum(scores)/len(scores)
    print(student,avg,end=' ')
```

Comment: Thank you for being kind and spending your time helping me NTamez8 you have explained it very thoroughly and I really appreciate it !!!!!!!!!!!!